# HDD spinning up while pc is off

Tags: hard-drive, spinup

We have a Dell PC that is switched off/shutdown (Mains still going into pc though), and every so often the HDD spins up for a couple of seconds then stops.
Does anyone know why this is and if it can be stopped?

Comment: just to add - you are 100% sure it is (and only) the hard drive spinning and not another form of hardware?

Comment: When this happens nothing else turns on? (like monitor output, keyboard, mouse, power supply fan, LEDs on the front panel...)

Comment: is the machine definitely off and not in sleep mode?

Comment: It is just the HDD, nothing else powering up or turning on and is definitely shutdown :)

Comment: is it Windows 8?
I've heard that instead of shutting down it enters some sleep mode that can still perform some low-power tasks without fully waking up.

Comment: No not windows 8, is WinXP

Comment: Could you please tell which exact model of a Dell PC is it?

Comment: it could be some circuit issue with the motherboard! i have seen a laptop's cpu fan spins to max speed as soon as there is power (battery or ac adapter)! lucky that was still under warranty...

Comment: optiplex 755 - Have checked all the wake up on lan/power savings options and nothing